# vue-gtag: getting ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT after implementation

Tags: vuejs3

I'm trying to implement vue-gtag to my Vue3 project, but right after following the [Get Started](https://matteo-gabriele.gitbook.io/vue-gtag/) and [Auto Tracking](https://matteo-gabriele.gitbook.io/vue-gtag/auto-tracking) documentation, I'm getting the following log in my browser:

GET https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-XXXXXXXXXX&l=dataLayer net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

I don't know what I've done wrong, but in order to better explain my implementation, that is it:

`createApp(App).use(router).use(VueGtag, { config: { id: G-XXXXXXXXXX } }, router).mount('#app')`

I also tried to add the plugin only in some pages as a test, but the same error occurs.

I am using Google Analytics 4, or GA4, and I don't know if this G-XXXXXXXXX, different from the previous UA-XXXXXXXX is the error cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might happen from ad blockers that block requests to trackers like Google analytics.

Try disabling any ad blockers in your browser

Comment: omg, I couldn't figure out ad blockers should be the problem. I'm a Brave Browser user, so I didn't install any extensions which block ads. Anyway, thank you so much!